# Moodle - Onde ficam informações de visualização de tarefas?

Tags: moodle

Estou tentando mudar um plugin e preciso descobrir onde o Banco de dados guarda informações de visualização de tarefas no moodle, o plugin é o progress bar e preciso disso urgente...

Comment: qual o tipo de tarefa que você deseja?

Answer (score 0):

O plugin do tipo bloco `progress` utiliza basicamente a tabela do moodle `mdl_log` para descobrir se tal `component` já foi visitado.

Abaixo um exemplo do código utilizado para obter acessos a um determinado component:

```
'pluginxxx' => array(
    'defaultTime' => 'openingtime',
    'actions' => array(
        'viewed' => array (
            'logstore_legacy'     => "SELECT id
                                        FROM {log}
                                       WHERE course = :courseid
                                         AND module = 'pluginxxx'
                                         AND action = 'view'
                                         AND cmid = :cmid
                                         AND userid = :userid",
            'sql_internal_reader' => "SELECT id
                                        FROM {log}
                                       WHERE courseid = :courseid
                                         AND component = 'mod_pluginxxx'
                                         AND action = 'viewed'
                                         AND objectid = :eventid
                                         AND userid = :userid",
        ),
    ),
    'defaultAction' => 'viewed'
)
```

Espero ter ajudado, se não for essa sua dúvida, seja mais específico para que possamos ajudá-lo.